# Dubious Literature

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking

My first puzzle. Please tell me if it's too vague.

> Hamlet: (*holding a sword*) To be or not to be.
>
> Horatio: Dear Hamlet, live! Only our present states diverge--our futures remain forever bound together.
>
> Hamlet: Nay Horatio, **OUR** ***pasts*** differ as well.
>
> Horatio: I see that **THEY** are indeed also different.

What word is Horatio thinking about?

Hint:

> I introduced one very important verb.

Hint 2:
I added this hint into the text.

Hint 3:

> Try reading the last 2 lines in different ways. In addition to the obvious meaning, there's a little bit of extra hidden meaning.

Hint 4:

> Pay attention to the bolded and bold/italicized text. Horatio and Hamlet are talking about forms of the same word.

Comment: too vague for me, but i'm a noob.... looks interesting... maybe in a day or two you will need to put some hints up...

Comment: Congratulations on your very first puzzle, and it looks good, too! I can't upvote as I have reached my daily voting limit (and have to wait $11$ hours), so I favourited $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: There, I gave it an upvote. That's a really good riddle

Comment: Spit balling a bit here but does the answer have anything to do with rot13:gvzr?

Answer (score 4):

Could Horatio's word be

> Bind? (And Hamlet's word is bound?)

This is because

> In the future, you will **be bound**; also you will **bound** the sheep's pasture. (The future tense of bind and bound is the same). In the present tense it differs (**bind** vs. **bound**). Similarly, the past tense of bind is **bound**...so Horatio might think that the past tenses are the same again...but the past tense of bound is **bounded**, so Hamlet is correct that they are not the same.

---

New idea (inspiration taken from @EightAndAHalfTails in the comments):

> Maybe capitalization is important. They say that **O**ur futures are bound together; but *o*ur presents are not. Further, *o*ur pasts diverge as well. The second hint makes me think that **O**ur pasts might not diverge. I'm not sure though whether the capital letters signify capitalization of the verb or whether they have slightly different meanings. I'm still not sure what the verb could be...

Comment: You are definitely on the right track, but Hamlet and Horatio are both discussing one verb.

Comment: Yes, I see now: Rot13(Gb O be abg gb O). @1848, was this pun intended? :P

Comment: @1848, in your Hint 2, didn't Hamlet say that already per the riddle? I don't see what changed...

Comment: @El-Guest capital 'O' in "Our," I think.

Comment: Hmm I intended capitalizing 'our' and 'they' in the last 2 lines to emphasize those 2 words. You can think of them as being bolded or italicized...ect

Comment: Would you like me to bold/italicize them? @1848

Comment: Sure. Maybe that would make things a little more clear? I added another hint as well.

Comment: I've changed the hint a little to make it more clear.

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails I think the difference is the question mark now...and thanks for the hint updates!

Comment: @El-Guest sorry if the question mark threw you off! It's only there because of 
'what if Hamlet said...?'

Comment: @1848, does that mean there are two different ways to read the same phrase? Because there are no differences if that is the case!

Comment: @El-Guest yeah. 'our' and 'they' are supposed to carry additional meaning. As for the important verb, if you're interested, Red Octopus's answer discusses the correct one. Maybe I'll add another hint since no one seems to be figuring out what I was trying to do in the last 2 lines.

Comment: If Red Octopus has the correct verb, then doesn't he have the right answer? I thought you had said it was the verb we were looking for. And sounds good, thanks very much! :D

Comment: @El-Guest I've made some more edits. Really sorry if this puzzle was unclear. I wrote it back when I hadn't seen that many puzzles yet!

Answer (score 2):

Are Horatio and Hamlet both talking about

> BE?

Reasoning:

Horatio: Dear Hamlet, live! Only our present states diverge--our futures remain forever bound together.

> "I **will be**" and "You **will be**" use the same conjugation. However, the present tenses diverge because "I **am**" and "You **are**".

Hamlet: Nay Horatio, OUR pasts differ as well.

> This is because "I **was**" and "You **were**". "We **were**" is also different from "I **was**".

Horatio: I see that THEY are indeed also different.

> And another one that's different from "I **was**": "They **were**".

Comment: You're 75% there. Horatio is talking about another meaning involving the bold/italicized words and your verb. If you take that route, Horatio is talking about one tense of your verb. But your present/future reasoning is what I had in mind.

Comment: How does this look @1848? There's a bit of jumping there but am I even closer now?

Comment: hmm I would say you are getting a little farther.

Answer (score 1):

Edit for second try:

Maybe Hamlet's word is

> "be"

while Horatio's word is

> "will"

"Our futures remain forever bound together" possibly refers to

> the future tense of "be" is accompanied by "will," as in "will be."

"Our present states diverge" and "our pasts differ"

> are reflected by the present tense of Hamlet's word ("am"/"are") and the past tense ("was"/"were") not needing to be preceded by "will"--"will am/are" and "will was/were" aren't grammatically correct!

---

**Original answer:**

Going off El-Guest's idea:

Perhaps it's the word

> "be", but either the singular or plural?

"Our present states diverge" may refer to

> "am" (singular) vs. "are" (plural)

While "Our futures remain forever bound together" refers to

> "will be" being the same future tense for both singular and plural.

However, their pasts differ:

> "was" (singular) vs. "were" (plural)

Comment: Your reasoning is pretty much there, but Horatio's word is incorrect.

Comment: Edited with another attempt!

Comment: Not quite, and I've added some more hints. I thought I was being clever when I came up with this puzzle, but I'll definitely try to make any futures puzzles less vague.

Answer (score 1):

I think the words are

> passed and past
>  passed is the past tense of pass
>  past is past tense of passen (archaic) which is probably related to the adjective 'past'

Comment: Not quite. Hint 4 means 'forms of the same word' literally (as in conjugations). Also the conjugations for 'to pass' don't quite match the rules I've set, but I can't say how or the answer becomes kind of obvious!